# How to cut an existing variable and assign to a new variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash

```
!/bin/bash
VAR=$(some curl commands)
token =$(cut -c 18-53 $VAR)
echo $token
```

I want to use VAR variable in my cut command but, when I use like this it says;

```
No such file or directory
```

I just wanna cut VAR(output of curl command) from 18.char to 53.char. Any suggestion ?

Comment: you can't put space between `token` and `=`

Comment: Honestly I don't see $VAR being used in cut anywhere

Comment: Go to your terminal, type `man bash`, search for the **Parameter Expansion** section, then look for `${parameter:offset:length}`. This is called "Substring Expansion", and is very well documented.

Comment: "out" should be  "$VAR". When I tried to txt file, I forget

Comment: The `#` in `#!/bin/bash` is significant. Your current shebang would traditionally cause the script file to be executed by `csh` which is not compatible with Bash.

Comment: I also thank you to @tripleee

Comment: Notice also the many errors pointed out by http://shellcheck.net/ if you paste in your script there.  It doesn't know about attempting to cut a variable, though.  Generally, you should probably fix all the errors pointed out by the automated tool before asking for human assistance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's define an example `var`:

```
$ var='The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog on the way to the market'
```

Now let's select characters 18 through 53 using `cut`:

```
$ echo $(cut -c 18-53 <<<"$var")
ox jumped over the lazy dog on the w
```

Because `cut` expects to read from standard input (if not a file), we use `<<<` to tell bash to provide the contents of `$var` on standard input.  This is called a *here string*.

Alternatively, we can select the same characters using bash alone:

```
$ echo ${var:17:36}
ox jumped over the lazy dog on the w
```

The construct `${var:17:36}` is called *substring expansion*.  It selects 36 characters starting from position 17. (In bash, unlike `cut`, the first character is numbered zero.)

We can, of course, assign the selected string to a variable:

```
$ token=${var:17:36}
$ echo "$token"
ox jumped over the lazy dog on the w
```

Or:

```
$ token=$(cut -c 18-53 <<<"$var")
$ echo "$token"
ox jumped over the lazy dog on the w
```

#### POSIX

The above commands work in bash.  If we want portability to POSIX shells, then we can use neither *substring expansion* nor *here strings*.  Instead, as [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) points out, we can use:

```
$ echo "$var" | cut -c 18-53
ox jumped over the lazy dog on the w
```

or:

```
$ token=$(echo "$var" | cut -c 18-53)
$ echo "$token"
ox jumped over the lazy dog on the w
```

[gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) suggests yet another POSIX method, this one avoiding external processes:

```
$ printf '%.36s\n' "${var#?????????????????}"
ox jumped over the lazy dog on the w
```

#### Comparison of `cut` and bash substring expansion

As [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) points out in the comments, there are strong advantages to uses bash's internal string handling.  One is that the use of bash's internal commands avoids the spawning of additional subshells and executables. If the additional subshells are spawned within a loop, this can greatly impact performance.

Also, command substitution has the side-effect of removing trailing newlines from its output.  This can cause unwanted surprises.  Using bash's internal string handling avoids this side-effect.

Comment: The benefit of using *string indexes* over *command substitution* and `cut` is you avoid spawning the additional subshells by using a builtin feature provided by bash. If additional subshells are spawned within a loop, this can greatly impact performance. (@Jon1024 - I know you know, this is just for the OP's benefit)

Comment: Just to clarify why the original version didn't work: `cut` expects its argument to be a *filename* to read from, not a string to operate on. What John1024's version does it *not* give it a filename (which `cut` implicitly treats as meaning to operate on its standard input, rather than a regular file), and then use a "here-string" to pass the string to `cut`'s standard input. The more traditional way to do this is `echo "$var" | cut -c 18-53` -- this is even slower, but will work in shells other than bash.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Good points!  Thank you.  I've added that to the answer.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Also good points!  I've added your POSIX version to the answer.

Comment: Note that `cut` works on lines (unless GNU `cut` is used with the `-z` option, then works on null-separated fields). So if the variable may contain newlines (and you really want a substring of the full variable), the `cut` solution is a no-go. A POSIX way could be a combination of `printf` and parameter expansion: `printf '%.36s\n' "${var#?????????????????}"` (of course, the long chain of `?`'s can be generated programmatically). But you're glad the question is tagged [tag:bash]!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - hah, fun. `printf '%.36s\n' "${var#$(printf '?%.0s' $(seq 1 17))}"`. Not quite POSIX, but `seq` is ubiquitous these days.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Very good.  I just updated the answer with your clever use of `printf`.